# How to populate an excel activex combobox

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do this with VBA, but everything I do does not work;

```
 Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Apple", 1
```

Nothing ever appears in the combo box and when I click the down arrow nothing happens. It seems its just stuck there and won't budge, I'm on dev mode. Thanks! Sorry I'm really new to excel

Comment: Can you share a little more like where is your combo box and where did you put the code for your combo box?

Comment: My combo box is in a plain sheet with nothing around it and for the code, I double click on the combo box, a file opens in which i can clearly see that it belongs to the sheet i'm working on juding my the left side file name (I'm using excel 2010) and it is where I wrote my line of code that you see above, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following (add to ThisWorkbook module):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1
      .AddItem "Apple"
   End With

End Sub
```

When you open the workbook,  the code will automatically update the combobox.